# PHP not recognising AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm calling a file via jQuery's AJAX method looks like this:

```
    $is_ajax = $_REQUEST['is_ajax'];
    if(isset($is_ajax) && $is_ajax)
    {
        echo 'its ajax!';
    }
    else echo 'im called, but not via ajax';
```

and my AJAX call:

```
jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'my-service.php',
                data: data,
                success: function(response) { 
                    alert(response);
                 }
            });
```

But alert always shows 'not ajax' message. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where did you define `is_ajax`?

Comment: How do you expect $_REQUEST to contain `is_ajax`?

Comment: Oh my dear, I forgot to include `is_ajax: 1` in data being sent. Too many hours in code right now...

Comment: you want to read this[http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/] ,here many samples, for used Ajax with Jquery, I thinks, Lex, and Muthu are the response, you want to define is_ajax value, in your Ajax's request...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Needed to add `is_ajax: 1` in data that is being sent via AJAX call.

Comment: I think @Florent should repost this for the answer

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your method of detecting AJAX is wrong. If your server supports HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH, then it's the way to go :

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
  /* special ajax here */
  die($content);
}
```

source : [Detect an AJAX Request](http://davidwalsh.name/detect-ajax)

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'my-service.php',
            data: {is_ajax:1},
            success: function(response) { 
                alert(response);
             }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

**Another method**

You can simple check whether the request is AJAX or not like this,

```
/* AJAX check  */
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
  echo 'its ajax!';
}else{
  echo 'im called, but not via ajax';
}
```

Comment: Who is setting the HTTP header? I wouldn't trust IE8 to insert this header.

Answer (score 1):

edit your AJAX call and modify the data

```
jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'my-service.php',
            data: {"is_ajax":"the value"},
            success: function(response) { 
                alert(response);
             }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
if(isset($_POST['is_ajax']))
{
    echo 'its ajax!';
}
else 
{
echo 'im called, but not via ajax';
}
```

Comment: @jan dvorak : y dont you answer then instead of commenting on every answer !!

Comment: @JanDvorak sufficient on what? they using more complex way. _POST is the standard way to receive on Ajax method.

Comment: @memosdp OP was using `$_REQUEST`, which is a valid way to access POST variables. OP was missing the POST variable he was testing.  This answer does not add the variable, only tests it in a different way./

Comment: @JanDvorak i misunderstood that you said about sufficiency ... it was for the sufficiency like an answer ... took me a while to realize it ... despite this not worths a downvote ... as you want